# How could I make this JSON data usable on an API?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, google-api-nodejs-client

JSON data currently looks like this string:

["ID","Name","Age"],["212","David","38"]

And I would like for it to look like this:

{"ID":"212","Name":"David","Age":"38"}

Thanks for your help in advance

I found this code and it solves most of the issue

```js
var columns = ["ID", "Name", "Age"];
var rows = ["212", "David", "38"];
var result =  rows.reduce(function(result, field, index) {
  result[columns[index]] = field;
  return result;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it's already usable JSON. that first string you posted is 100% valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to this, ok I see your point, but how could I make that JSON look like this {"ID":"212","Name":"David","Age":"38"}

Comment: It's already JSON, just like that.. Maybe if you posted some code it would be easier to see what your actual problem is.

Comment: I think he wants a JSON object structured like this csv is structured.

Comment: I Edited the question for it to make more sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with following steps:

1. extract keys and values from array
2. zip them to key match value
3. use Object.fromEntries to create object key-value

```js
let obj = [["ID","Name","Age"],["212","David","38"]]
let [keys, values] = obj;
let zipped = keys.map((key, i)=>[key, values[i]]);
let output = Object.fromEntries(zipped);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This code worked beautifully, well I had to update to the latest version of nodejs in order for the fromEntries function to work.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi Taher for your answer, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

lets say
let jsonVal = [["ID","Name","Age"],["212","David","38"], ["212","David","38"]]
0th index will have the keys  and remaining is data

```
let newJsonVal = []  ​
 for (let i =1; i< jsonVal.length-1; i++) {
    ​let newObject ={}
     ​jsonVal[i].map((d,j) => { 
       ​newObject[jsonVal[0][j] = d;
      ​})
    newJsonVal.push(newObject)
 }
```

newJsonVal will have  array of object as you need