# Why is this map for loop code not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dictionary, for-loop

Someone with experience should be able to understand the error with ease, but for me it is hard, I tried learning online about map and for loop but no luck understanding the error, can someone please help me.

```js
let jsonVal = [["ID","Name","Age"],["212","David","38"],["213","Mike","42"]]

let newJsonVal = [] ​
 for (let i =1; i< jsonVal.length-1; i++) {
    ​let newObject ={}
     ​jsonVal[i].map((d,j) => { 
       ​newObject[jsonVal[0][j] = d]
      ​})
    newJsonVal.push(newObject);
     console.log(newJsonVal);
 }
```

The output should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "212",
    "Name": "David",
    "Age": "38"
  },
  {
    "ID": "213",
    "Name": "Mike",
    "Age": "42"
  }
]
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: There are illegal characters, which the error states in clear english, and if those are removed, it doesn't throw any error. You further didn't state what the error should be, nor what the code is supposed to do, so i have no clue, what you are talking about.

Comment: For starters, hit "Run code snippet" and see the output -- you have a syntax error `newObject[jsonVal[0][j] = d]` is not valid.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Comment: Ah, i understand now, typical SO, someone posts a syntactically incorrect answer, OP fails at copy&paste, and makes a new question about it without context - and gets upvoted. Good stuff.

Comment: You have an answer but it doesn't actually tell you why your code wasn't working. I looked at the code with a hex editor and you have hidden characters on a couple of lines. Removing those characters allows your code to work. If you had typed out this code in the first place it would have worked. One of the dangers of copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228282/how-could-i-make-this-json-data-usable-on-an-api/69228578?noredirect=1#comment122385014_69228578) but this time with multiple objects:

```js
let jsonVal = [["ID","Name","Age"],["212","David","38"],["213","Mike","42"]]
let [keys, ...objs] = jsonVal;
let newJsonVal = []
objs.map((obj, i)=>{
    const newObj = keys.map((key, i)=>[key, obj[i]]);
    newJsonVal.push(Object.fromEntries(newObj));
})
console.log(newJsonVal)
```

Comment: Mehdi Taher you are here to safe me again,  you are awesome.. Thank you again !!

Comment: You're welcome again :)

Comment: This code works perfectly!!